# Retrieve Maven classpath from configuration

Tags: maven, maven-2

I need to somehow find the classpath for maven, i.e. all dependencies, etc... and use it as part of the configuration for a plugin. Here is an example

```
    ...<systemProperties>
        <systemProperty>
          <name>some.system.property.here</name>
          <value>${maven.runtime.classpath}</value>
        </systemProperty>
     </systemProperties>
    </configuration>...
```

Unfortunately property ${maven.runtime.classpath} is empty. Is there anything that is the equivalent of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use something like groovy and set it up programatically.

Here is the config that needs to be included.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <source>
                    import org.codehaus.plexus.util.StringUtils;
                    import java.io.File;

                    System.setProperty("your.classpath.property", StringUtils.join(project.getRuntimeClasspathElements().iterator(), File.pathSeparator));
                </source>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly why the classpath is empty, maybe this will help:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

Comment: In all fairness I am trying to do this from jetty maven plugin. Also, the above link related to using ant which I cannot make it execute before jetty:run